# Impossible to load an image in xcassets on bundle

Tags: ios, static-libraries, nsbundle, xcasset

I need to include images in a static library. 
I created a bundle and inserted in my images, the problem is that it seems to work if I include the images directly in the bundle, but stops working if I put in a xcassets file.

I followed many guides and searched for a solution on this site. 
The most popular solution is to insert this line of code:

```
[UIImage imageNamed:@"MyBundle.bundle/imageName"]
```

but it seems not work for me

any ideas?

Comment: facing same issue, Did you able to fix this?

Comment: @BaSha it is possible using iOs 8 with this method:
+ (UIImage *)imageNamed:(NSString *)name inBundle:(NSBundle *)bundle compatibleWithTraitCollection:(UITraitCollection *)traitCollection;
With iOs 7 the best solution is remove the images from the xcassets file

Comment: thanks, though I had to add images separately in bundle as iOS 7 support was required

Comment: @BaSha I created this category https://gist.github.com/serluca/e4f6a47ffbc19fccc63e . In this way, you can use after: [NSBundle imageNamed:@"imageName"];

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are two ways to solve this,

If your app is still supporting iOs 7, you can use this category:
https://gist.github.com/serluca/e4f6a47ffbc19fccc63e

Otherwise, starting from iOs 8 Apple added a way to do this using:
`+ imageNamed:inBundle:compatibleWithTraitCollection:` defined [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImage_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIImage/imageNamed:inBundle:compatibleWithTraitCollection:)

Comment: know of any way to refer to this inside Interface Builder?

Comment: I did but that refers to a png, rather than an .xcassets identifier. Having said that I didn't realise but my problem goes a little deeper because it's not importing assets from my custom framework. I will try it again after (hopefully) I out out my other issue. Thanks!

Comment: imageNamed:inBundle:compatibleWithTraitCollection: works with a PNG embedded in the bundle flat, but once you put it in the .xcassets folder, I cannot find a way of referring to it anymore...

Answer (score 8):

Running the same problem. Looks like inline bundle support is broken for XCAssets in the 1-parameter imageNamed method. There's a workaround though using imageNamed:inBundle:compatibleWithTraitCollection: Be careful, this is iOS8 only !!

```
NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle bundleWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"static_lib_bundle_name" ofType:@"bundle"]];
UIImage *image  = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image_in_the_xcassets_you_want" inBundle:bundle compatibleWithTraitCollection:nil];
```

NOTE : traitCollection is set to nil to pass the main screen traits as per [apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/Reference/UIImage_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIImage/imageNamed:inBundle:compatibleWithTraitCollection:) (i don't quite get what it means though, if anyone knows please comment!).

Comment: So I've been having the same issue, looks like the scenario is that xcode compile xcassets directly to a binary file (.car) and copies into main bundle, which mean xcassets cannot be contained in a bundle resource.

https://devforums.apple.com/message/968859#968859

Answer (score 3):

For Swift 2.1:

```
let bundle = pathToBundle // define for your app or framework
if let image = UIImage(named: "drop_arrow", inBundle: bundle, compatibleWithTraitCollection: nil) {
    // process image
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Our images are placed in Images.xcassets and we had a problem with loading images in an IBDesignable. The following code did the job for the preview in Interface builder and the app as well:

```
NSBundle* bundle = [NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]];
UIImage* image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.jpg" inBundle:bundle compatibleWithTraitCollection:nil];
```

Comment: As I said this method is available on starting from iOs 8. If you use iOs 7 you can use my category instead https://gist.github.com/serluca/e4f6a47ffbc19fccc63e