# Can't load images from .xcasset in CocoaPods

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, cocoapods

I'm creating a pod and I have an image asset catalog I'd like to use.
In my .podspec file, I have it set up like this:

```
s.resource_bundles = {
  'MyPodResources' => ['*.xcassets']
}
```

and the Images.xcassets is in the root directory of the pod.

When I'm try to load images using `imageNamed()`, it's just not working. I don't get an error or a warning but no images are displayed.

Here's the fun part - if I try to add an image in my Main.storyboard in the example application, I can select the image and it's showing up fine in the Interface Builder. However, when I run the example app, the image is not visible.

I've looked through all issues on GH and still can't find a solution to this ... Is it an Xcode 7/iOS 9 issue?

Thanks!

Comment: Seem like a problem of target membership

Comment: What is 'imageLoad'? If you're using imageNamed function, it loads image from default bundle, so you have to specify MyPodResources bundle directly to load image from there. Try to use solution from this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26158980/impossible-to-load-an-image-in-xcassets-on-bundle

Comment: @Iyuna sorry, meant imageNamed. Will try to load it from the bundle, but during my research I found info that that shouldn't be needed with CocoaPods - it should automatically include the bundle somehow ...

Comment: Did you ever figure it out?

Comment: @KingPolygon thanks for reminding me - I have actually solved it, check my answer below.

Answer (score 8):

In the end, I wrote an extension for `UIImage` and put it in the pod directory. It looks like this:

```
class func bundledImage(named: String) -> UIImage? {
    let image = UIImage(named: named)
    if image == nil {
        return UIImage(named: named, inBundle: NSBundle(forClass: MyBasePodClass.classForCoder()), compatibleWithTraitCollection: nil)
    } // Replace MyBasePodClass with yours
    return image
}
```

I'm using it like:
`imageView.image = UIImage.bundledImage("icon-grid")`

That's it, hope someone finds this useful!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and found a small but important piece of info about the .podspec file

I was trying to use an image from my pods bundle thats inside a .xcassets in the storyboard, it would show fine in the storyboard but when i ran the app it would crash saying it cant find the resource.

I changed my podspec to include `s.resources` as well as `s.resource_bundles`

```
s.resource_bundles = {
  'SDKRes' => ['SDK/Assets/*']
}

s.resources = ['SDK/Assets/*.{xcassets}']
```

Then it was able to load the resource properly from the storyboard

Comment: Thank you Fonix , you saved me after a lot of struggling.

Answer (score 1):

in Swift 3:

```
let bundle: Bundle = Bundle(identifier: "Framework Bundle ID")!
yourImageView.image =  UIImage(named: "imageNameInAssets", in: bundle, compatibleWith: nil)
```

Answer (score 1):

I bumped into this issue and fixed it by the following method.

### Assets.xcassets Can't be loaded

I put my icon images in Assets.xcassets at first, but I can't read my images in it.

### Use .bundle instead

Put your icon images in bundle. Creating a bundle is easy.

1. Create a folder.
2. Copy your images into this folder.
3. Add .bundle as this folder's subtitle
4. drag this .bundle into your project

### Edit resource in your .podspec

```
s.resource_bundles = {'<YourBundleName>' => ['*.bundle']}
```

Note that if your enter a different name here will rename your bundle!

### Create a class to help you get your image in bundle

```
class ImageHelper {
static func image(_ name: String) -> UIImage? {
    let podBundle = Bundle(for: ImageHelper.self) // for getting pod url
    if let url = podBundle.url(forResource: "<YourBundleName>", withExtension: "bundle") { //<YourBundleName> must be the same as you wrote in .podspec
        let bundle = Bundle(url: url)
        return UIImage(named: name, in: bundle, compatibleWith: nil)
    }
    return UIImage()
}
```

### Get Your Image

```
ImageHelper.image("<YourImageName>")
```

Hope this helps.