# iOS cocoapods include xcassets in podspec for multi module project

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, assets, podspec

I have multi project iOS app which used `cocoapods` `podspec` to maintain each project as a `dynamic` `framework`. Each project has its own images in `Assets.xcasset` and multiple other resource (`xib`, `ttf`, `json`...).

I'm using below `podspec` (which use `resource_bundles` to separate resource for each pod (my pod `xcassets` contain of multiple vector `pdf` file `imageset`)

```
Pod::Spec.new do |spec|
    moduleName = 'UIComponent'
    spec.name = moduleName
    spec.version = '0.0.7'
    spec.summary = "#{spec.name} function"

    spec.description = <<-DESC
    #{spec.name} helpful function
                   DESC
    spec.homepage = 'https://bitbucket.org/ascendcorp/ami-ios-customer-app'

    spec.license = 'MIT'
    spec.author = { 'xxxx' => 'xxx' }

    spec.platform = :ios, '13.0'
    spec.ios.deployment_target = '13.0'
    spec.swift_version = '5.3'

    spec.source = {
        git: '#{my_git}',
        branch: 'develop',
        # tag: "#{spec.version}",
    }

    spec.source_files = "#{spec.name}", "#{spec.name}/**/*.{h,m,swift}"
    spec.resource_bundles = {
        "#{spec.name}" => [
            "#{spec.name}/**/*.{lproj,xcdatamodeld,xib,json,ttf,xcassets}",
        ],
    }
    spec.exclude_files = "#{spec.name}/Exclude"
    spec.public_header_files = "#{spec.name}/**/*.h"
    spec.static_framework = false

    spec.dependency 'Core'

    spec.dependency 'RxSwift'
    spec.dependency 'RxCocoa'
    spec.dependency 'CoreList'
    spec.dependency 'SVProgressHUD'
    spec.dependency 'Material'
    spec.dependency 'Nuke'
end
```

The problem is with

```
spec.resource_bundles = {
        "#{spec.name}" => [
            "#{spec.name}/**/*.{lproj,xcdatamodeld,xib,json,ttf,xcassets}",
        ],
    }
```

I can see all the resouce being copy to my `Development Pods` (including `xib`, `Assets.xcassets` folder) but seem our normal reference not working (get bellow error)

```
Could not load the "ic_xxx" image referenced from a nib in the bundle with identifier "org.cocoapods.xxxx"
```

even my normal xib allocation also not work

```
super.init(nibName: "SplashViewController", bundle: Bundle(for: SplashViewController.self))
```

for image also not work

```
img = UIImage(named: name, in: Bundle(for: aClass), compatibleWith: nil)
```

What is the correct way to reference `resource` (`Assets.xcassets`, `xib`...) using `spec.resource_bundles`? Note: I cannot use `spec.resources` as it will cause duplicate and fail the build.

Comment: No hints there https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35692265/how-to-load-resource-in-cocoapods-resource-bundle ? Also, if you do `Bundle(for: SplashViewController.self).resourceURL` can you navigate in the folder hierarchy to find your ressources?

Comment: hi @Larme i can use 
`let bundle = Bundle(for: Self.self)
        let resourceUrl = bundle.resourceURL?.appendingPathComponent("CommonService.bundle")
        print("resourceUrl \(resourceUrl)")
        let resourceBundle = Bundle(url: resourceUrl!)
        super.init(nibName: "DropdownViewController", bundle: resourceBundle)` 
for xib but for xcassets i tried the bellow but not working

Comment: `let image1 = UIImage(named: "ic_checkbox_on", in: resourceBundle, compatibleWith: nil)`

Comment: I meant to see by using `try? FileManager.default.contents(atPath: resourceUrl.path)` and so on in the debugger to find the image. Maybe there https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33063233/cant-load-images-from-xcasset-in-cocoapods ?

Comment: seem like i have `nil` with above query  `let test1 = try? FileManager.default.contents(atPath: resourceUrl!.path)`
using`let resourceUrl = bundle.resourceURL?.appendingPathComponent("CommonService.bundle")`

Comment: using finder, using `resourceUrl` i can navigate to `CommonService.bundle` inside i see my xib file and a `Assets.car` folder. seem like having problem retrieve image from `Assets.car`